# Customize Grails generated views

Tags: jquery-ui, grails, yui, grails-2.0

Is it possible to customize code generated from grails create view command? for example can I use YUI or JQuery UI library for view code generation? Is there any sample for that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the Grails command `grails install-templates` will copy into `src/templates` the template files used by all of the other Grails commands to generate files. You can then modify them however you wish.

Also, you may wish to look at some of the scaffolding plugins, such as [Grails Twitter Bootstrap Scaffolding](http://grails-twitter-bootstrap.cloudfoundry.com/) or [Enhanced Scaffolding](https://github.com/robfletcher/grails-enhanced-scaffolding).